# RKE OpenStack cloud provider without scheduled pods

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I'm trying to use [openstack-cloud-controller-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/blob/master/docs/openstack-cloud-controller-manager/using-openstack-cloud-controller-manager.md) with Rancher RKE. I'm using application credentials to access openstack and for this reason it appears to me that I cannot use the [openstack-provider](https://rke.docs.rancher.com/config-options/cloud-providers/openstack) that RKE has by default because there are no parameters on that. However, I noticed that these parameters are available with the official [openstack-cloud-controller-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/blob/master/docs/openstack-cloud-controller-manager/using-openstack-cloud-controller-manager.md#global) install under the `global` section.

Now I tried to install the OpenStack provider in the following way:

- Install RKE (v1.24) without its own openstack provider and set the kubelet argument `cloud-provider` to `external`:

```
  services {
    kubelet {
      extra_args = {
        cloud-provider = "external"
      }
    }
  }
```

with master nodes with both the role `controlplane` and `etcd`.

- Install the [openstack-cloud-controller-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master) (steps inspired by the openmetal post [here](https://openmetal.io/docs/manuals/kubernetes-guides/installing-the-kubernetes-openstack-cloud-controller-manager)):

Create a configuration file:

```
[Global]
cloud=openstack
auth-url=https://openstack.com:5000
username=username
user-id=id
password=pass
tenant-id=tenant_id
tenant-name=tenant_name
region=RegionOne
ca-file=/my/local/adacloud.ca.chain
application-credential-id=cred_id
application-credential-secret=cred_secret

[LoadBalancer]
use-octavia=true
floating-network-id=ext_network_id
subnet-id=cluster_subnet_id
```

Create a secret from it:

```
kubectl create secret -n kube-system generic cloud-config --from-file=local/openstack.conf
```

Download manifests:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/master/manifests/controller-manager/cloud-controller-manager-roles.yaml
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/master/manifests/controller-manager/cloud-controller-manager-role-bindings.yaml
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/master/manifests/controller-manager/openstack-cloud-controller-manager-ds.yaml
```

I changed the `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector` in the file `openstack-cloud-controller-manager-ds.yaml` in the following way:

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane: "true"
```

> This is because the nodes are labeled by default as `controlplane=true`

The tolerations in the `openstack-cloud-controller-manager-ds.yaml` file are:

```
tolerations:
- key: node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized
value: "true"
effect: NoSchedule
- key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
effect: NoSchedule
- key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
effect: NoSchedule
```

Then I applied them:

```
kubectl apply -f cloud-controller-manager-roles.yaml
kubectl apply -f cloud-controller-manager-role-bindings.yaml
kubectl apply -f openstack-cloud-controller-manager-ds.yaml
```

Finally, when I check the daemonsets, there are no pods..

```
$ kubectl get -n kube-system ds
NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                               AGE
canal                                4         4         4       4            4           kubernetes.io/os=linux                      17m
openstack-cloud-controller-manager   0         0         0       0            0           node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true   11s
```

I have the following labels, annotations and taints on the master node:

```
Labels:             app=ingress
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-master-0
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true
Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VNI":1,"VtepMAC":"3e:96:d7:c9:94:f8"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 192.168.4.165
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 192.168.4.165/24
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 10.42.0.1
                    rke.cattle.io/external-ip: 192.168.4.165
                    rke.cattle.io/internal-ip: 192.168.4.165
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true:NoExecute
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true:NoSchedule
                    node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized=true:NoSchedule
```

I cannot understand why these pods are not scheduled. Is there someone who already run in that issue?

PS. I tried also without the kubelet arg `cloud-provider=external`, but with no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to solve this issue.

The problem is that I created the control plane nodes with both the roles `controlplane` *and* `etcd`. As described in the [SUSE support website](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020116), by looking at the taints we can see that not only there is `node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true:NoSchedule`, but also `node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true:NoExecute` which prevents any pod to be scheduled:

```
kubectl get node k8s-master -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints
NAME                    TAINTS
k8s-master              [map[effect:NoSchedule key:node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane value:true] map[effect:NoExecute key:node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd value:true]]
```

By adding the following tolerations in the `openstack-cloud-controller-manager` `DaemonSet`, pods are scheduled correctly:

```
spec:
  ...
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane: "true"
      tolerations:
      ...
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane
        value: "true"
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd
        value: "true"
        effect: NoExecute
```

I link also another useful resource I found on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/issues/2093).

Answer (score 0):

looking it over, seems the openstack-cloud-controller-manager needs the
node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true:NoSchedule toleration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does no work. DaemonSet shows 0 pods. I added to `tolerations:`
```
- key: node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane \n
  value: "true" \n
  effect: NoSchedule
```